# Appium unable to open app with real device iOS

Tags: ios, appium

Here is what I set as capabilities in appium server :

```
{
  "deviceName": "andrew's iPhone",
  "platformVersion": "10.3.3(14G60)",
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "udid": "cc917xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "app": " /Users/test/Downloads/mydemo.ipa",
  "automationName": "XCUITest"
}
```

Same capabilities works if I use default simulator rather than real device.

**Error :**

```
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Bad app: /Users/test/Downloads/mydemo.ipa. App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name.
```

Note : IPA already developer certi. signed.

Appium Log :

```
[BaseDriver] Copying local zip to tmp dir
[XCUITest] Error: Local zip did not exist
    at copyLocalZip$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/basedriver/helpers.js:104:11)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke]
```

Comment: Did you still try using a `.app` to debug?

Comment: @nullpointer - Yes but it has also same isssue. working fine with simulator but not with real device.

Comment: @nullpointer - I have added appium log if that helps.